# OLS and ARCH Error Term

Tags: least-squares, error, garch, unbiased-estimator

As for an OLS equation,

[image]

If the error term has ARCH, i.e.

[image]

Is the OLS estimator still unbiased?

Comment: Hi: I didn't read carefully but based on the link below, it seems that estimates are unbiased but not efficient. http://sfb649.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/fedc_homepage/xplore/tutorials/xegbohtmlnode53.html

Comment: Hello, the answer is yes. But due to the heteroscedasticity, the OLS estimator is not efficient and the paramters are usually estimated via ML. Another nice result is that (under some regularity conditions) the information matrix is block diagonal and therefore you can estimate the mean equation and the variance equation separately. However, in most cases the mean equation and variance equation are estimated together.

Comment: If this is a homework question, please add the [tag:self-study] tag and read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).